# How to combine rows in groupby with several conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine rows in pandas df with the following logic:

- dataframe is grouped by users
- rows are ordered by start_at_min
- rows are combiend when:

Case A:
if start_at_min<=200:

- row1[stop_at_min] - row2[start_at_min] < 5
- (eg: 101 -100 = 1 -> **combine**; 200-100=100: -> **dont combine**)

Case Bif 200> start_at_min<400:

- change threhsold to 3

Case C if start_at_min>400:

- Never combine

Example df

```py
   user  start_at_min  stop_at_min
0     1           100          150  
1     1           152          201 #row0 with row1 combine
2     1           205          260 #row1 with row 2 NO -> start_at_min above 200 -> threshol =3 
3     2            65          100 #no
4     2           200          265 #no
5     2           300          451 #no
6     2           452          460 #no -> start_at_min above 400-> never combine
```

Expected output:

```py
   user  start_at_min  stop_at_min
0     1           100          201 #row1 with row2 combine
2     1           205          260 #row2 with row 3 NO -> start_at_min above 200 -> threshol =3 
3     2            65          100 #no
4     2           200          265 #no
5     2           300          451 #no
6     2           452          460 #no -> start_at_min above 400-> never combine
```

I have written the funciton combine_rows, that takes in 2 Series and applies this logic

```py
def combine_rows (s1:pd.Series, s2:pd.Series):
  # take 2 rows and combine them if start_at_min row2 - stop_at_min row1 < 5 
  if s2['start_at_min'] - s1['stop_at_min'] <5: 
     return pd.Series({
         'user': s1['user'],
         'start_at_min': s1['start_at_min'],
         'stop_at_min' : s2['stop_at_min']
         })
  else: 
    return pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1).T
```

Howver I am unable to apply this function to the dataframe.
This was my attempt:

```py
df.groupby('user').sort_values(by=['start_at_min']).apply(combine_rows) # this not working
```

Here is the full code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user"       :  [1, 1, 2,2],
    'start_at_min': [60, 101, 65, 200], 
    'stop_at_min' : [100, 135, 100, 265] 
})

def combine_rows (s1:pd.Series, s2:pd.Series):
  # take 2 rows and combine them if start_at_min row2 - stop_at_min row1 < 5 
  if s2['start_at_min'] - s1['stop_at_min'] <5: 
     return pd.Series({
         'user': s1['user'],
         'start_at_min': s1['start_at_min'],
         'stop_at_min' : s2['stop_at_min']
         })
  else: 
    return pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1).T

df.groupby('user').sort_values(by=['start_at_min']).apply(combine_rows) # this not working
```

Comment: Are there always two rows for each user or can there be more or less?

Comment: There can be more rows per user.

Comment: What happens if we add another row with `1, 133, 150`? Does the output become `1,60,150`?

Comment: This is impossible, as they cannot overlap. 
so it would have to be 1, 136, 150 -> and then it would combine into one 1, 60, 150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### version 1: one condition

Perform a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
threshold = 5
# if the successive stop/start per group are above threshold
# start a new group
group = (df['start_at_min']
         .sub(df.groupby('user')['stop_at_min'].shift())
         .ge(threshold).cumsum()
        )

# groupby.agg
out = (df.groupby(['user', group], as_index=False)
         .agg({'start_at_min': 'min',
               'stop_at_min': 'max'
              })
      )
```

Output:

```
   user  start_at_min  stop_at_min
0     1            60          135
1     2            65          100
2     2           200          265
```

Intermediate:

```
(df['start_at_min']
 .sub(df.groupby('user')['stop_at_min'].shift())
)

0      NaN
1      1.0  # below threshold, this will be merged
2      NaN
3    100.0  # above threshold, keep separate
dtype: float64
```

##### version 2: multiple conditions

```
# define variable threshold
threshold = np.where(df['start_at_min'].le(200), 5, 3)
# array([3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5])

# compute the new starts of group like in version 1
# but using the now variable threshold
m1 = (df['start_at_min']
         .sub(df.groupby('user')['stop_at_min'].shift())
         .ge(threshold)    
        )
# add a second restart condition (>400)
m2 = df['start_at_min'].gt(400)

# if either mask is True, start a new group
group = (m1|m2).cumsum()

# groupby.agg
out = (df.groupby(['user', group], as_index=False)
         .agg({'start_at_min': 'min',
               'stop_at_min': 'max'
              })
      )
```

Output:

```
   user  start_at_min  stop_at_min
0     1           100          201
1     1           205          260
2     2            65          100
3     2           200          265
4     2           300          451
5     2           452          460
```

Comment: thanks, 
my fault for making the example to simplisitc, In my real case I have many conditions that need to be satisfied for a grouping to happen (eg: if start_at_min >400: do not combine).

this is why I wrote a separate function to capture all the condition. Tried to simplify here for clarity, but maybe made it too simple.

Comment: You can still incorporate your other conditions in a vectorial manner, can you update the example?

Comment: i have added 2 other conditions: 
# if start_at_min >= 200 --> the threshold changes to 3
# is start_at_min >400 --> never combine

Comment: amazing...would have never been able to find a solution like this thanks !